# C# Directshow Stream Filter

Tags: c#, directshow.net, webm

I'm using DirectShow .NET to capture WebM Videos. 
The Graph looks like this:

[image: Graph]

My question is, how can i use the "preview" pin from VP8 encoder to stream a preview video?
Is there any (free) DirectShow filter available for this job?
Or is the preview pin the wrong way?

**Edit:**
The "Enhanced Video Renderer" is the renderer to show the video in a window. It works properly but is just an example. I have a Webservice (WCF) and want to stream the live capture through the network simultaneously to the filewriter. (Filewriter in the graph "test.webm") I think i doesn't need a custom solution here. There are filters for showing the video in a Window. i simply need a filter with a streaming output. The rendering process is part of the browser side. How can i achieve this?

In other words: Im searching a stream writer filter or something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "stream"? If you're just trying to display the video on the screen: from my admittedly long-ago experience with DirectShow, it seems to me that you should be able to use a renderer, just as you show in the graph. What exactly is "Enhanced Video Renderer 0000"? Are you sure it's compatible with the video format output from the `Preview` pin? If you're literally trying to stream video data over a network or something like that, you'll of course need a renderer that knows how to do that. If you're simply looking for a recommendation of 3rd party library, that's off-topic here.

Comment: The "Enhanced Video Renderer" is the renderer to show the video in a window. It works properly but is just an example. I have a Webservice (WCF) and want to stream the live capture through the network simultaneously to the filewriter. (Filewriter in the graph "test.webm") I think i doesn't need a custom solution here. There are filters for showing the video in a Window. i simply need a filter with a streaming output. The rendering process is part of the browser side. How can i achieve this?